# char* array of pointers modification

Tags: arrays, c, string, function, pointers

I am new to c language after learning python and java and I encountered an interesting exercise that i cannot find answer online for.

Given an *char array of pointers to string (*char arr[N(N is defined)]={"sadsd","gasgs"......})

what is the proper way to pass given array of string pointers to a function so that the function will be able to modify the array?

For example if i want to print the array with a different position for each element in it? After i pass the array pointer to the function I cant modify the array for some reason without using [] do define the elements I want to work on. the exercise is to use pointer arithmetics without using [].

thank you and have a great day :)

Comment: a[i] is the same as *(a+i)

Comment: @spkersten thank you for your answer, is the better way to change pointer values or the content of the pointed adress ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing an array of strings to a function can be done with a declaration like this :

```
void function(char ** strArray);
```

The size cannot be found from such a pointer so it should be passed too :

```
void function(char ** strArray, int arraySize);
```

Indices are accessible with [] from 0 to arraySize-1. Pointer arithmetic allow doing the same with a different syntax :

```
strArray[5]     // Gives a string (whose the size could then be found with strlen)
*(strArray + 5) // Equivalent form using pointer arithmetic
```

Here is an example printing the array content after having changed the second index :

```
void printStringArrayContent(char ** array, int size) {
    *(array + 1) = "Margaret";
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
        printf("%s ", *(array + i));
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void main(){
    char * array[3] = { "John", "Sarah", "Michael" };
    printStringArrayContent(array, 3); //==> John Margaret Michael
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU so much,i was bashing my head trying to figure out why trying to access the second element of the array i only get the first element minus the 2 first chars. thanks ^^ also, your answer is amazing and super informative thumbs up !